# angularjs dirty checking rate

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was reading some article to understand a little bit more how **angular.js** works.

I understood what is '**dirty checking($digest)**'.

But on what rate the watchers are listening for dirty fields?

And whats the minimum rate at which angular can update the **$scope** variable changes?

Comment: Read this one, https://www.airpair.com/angularjs focus in the last part the form validation. Initially elements has a class of `pristine` meaning untouched, so once the value of it changes it will be marked as `dirty` and you can only revert it back to pristine once you refresh the page

Comment: @MidTwo, thanks for the aricle, good read.
But my question is on how much time is required  to complete one cycle.Is that dependent on how many watchers we have?

Comment: one digest cycle depends on how many watchers you have and what are the processes underneath that watchers, so this is the time where performance topic comes in. Less watchers = Greater performance of your page

Comment: I think your question incomplete. Can you elaborate it ??

Answer (score 1):

one time changes on field. watcher check the once time changes